# How to return a numeric substring given exceptions?

Tags: sql, oracle

It is necessary to pull out numerical sequences consisting of 5 or 6 digits,
excluding numeric sequences containing sequences of letters on the left side 'CR', 'MRLID_', 'GEO_'. The first hyphen is not a search key

My example:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('84830-Soc_Dem-Carousel-CR236666',
                     '([^CR\d{6}]+)|([^MRLID_\d{5}]+)|([GEO_\d{5}]+)\d{5,6}',
                     1,
                     1,
                     'i')
  FROM dual
```

If input string
has the following form:

```
'McCombo_Mar-Apr11119_mcd_installs;759678/;CR759428-Soc_Dem-Multi_roll_15sec-R27?<MRLID_12345>%GEO_78934?]ysl_fraw_blackopium_display_aw'
```

It is necessary to pull out the value 759678. This is a numeric sequence, it can consist of 5 or 6 characters, it can be located anywhere in the line, it is not possible to somehow select it with a separator.

Comment: What you want to manage is not clear. Basically seems to extract the piece upto the first hyphen, but the current patten is confusing...

Comment: @Barbaros Özha
It is necessary to pull out numerical sequences consisting of 5 or 6 digits, excluding numeric sequences containing sequences of letters on the left side 'CR', 'MRLID_', 'GEO_'. The first hyphen is not a search key.

Comment: it would be better to share some sample data and desired result I think.

Comment: The task description contains an example result and input data for processing 
under the tags: "Need result:","My code return don t result:". Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: In order to understand what exactly you want throughout the table. If extracting only the substring upto the first hyphen is the case, then even a regex function is not needed. We should clearly see including exceptional cases somebody help you  well.

Comment: I provided an example with additional description, thanks for pointing the question in the right direction.

Comment: Your original question wanted 84830, but now you’ve edited your question to want a number of 5 or 6 digits, but that would mean returning 236666 not 84830. Please clarify. Also, is the only requirement digits? So would 759428 qualify from your second example if it did not also contain 759678? Or must the number not be beside letters?

Comment: Yes, number not be beside letters. 
Сhoose first number satisfying condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REGEXP_SUBSTR with a regex to get a number with 5 to 6 digits that's not proceeded by a letter or digit, and not followed by a letter/digit/underscore.

> ```
> with DATA as (
>   select '84830-Soc_Dem-Carousel-CR236666' String from dual
>   union all select 'McCombo_Mar-Apr11119_mcd_installs;759678/;CR759428-Soc_Dem-Multi_roll_15sec-R27?<MRLID_12345>%GEO_78934?]ysl_fraw_blackopium_display_aw' from dual
>   union all select 'Couriers_75942-Soc_Dem-Multi_roll_15sec-R27_McCombo_Mar-Apr19_mcd_installs' from dual
> ) 
> select REGEXP_SUBSTR(String, '(^|[^[:alnum:]])([[:digit:]]{5,6})([^[:alnum:]_]|$)',1,1,'',2) as ID
> from DATA;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ID     |
> | :----- |
> | 84830  |
> | 759678 |
> | 75942  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5e0fae19493c65d314690894ba2b30f)*

Comment: Thanks. if symbol "underscore" data: 'Couriers_75942-Soc_Dem-Multi_roll_15sec-R27_McCombo_Mar-Apr19_mcd_installs'. 
Can your code be adapted to the "underscore" character?

Comment: So it can start with an underscore then. Just remove `_` from `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])`.  A `[^_]` means no underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_replace` instead to replace `-.*` with blank:

```
select regexp_replace('84830-Soc_Dem-Carousel-CR236666', '-.*','') from dual
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44d2f4c0db1be33572151862a1b46281).

Comment: Bohemian, Im additional exercise

Comment: Bohemian, You replace all 
symbols to the void after hyphen. Im additional exercise.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'McCombo_Mar-Apr19_mcd_installs;759678/;CR759428-Soc_Dem-Multi_roll_15sec-R27?<MRLID_12345>%GEO_78934?]ysl_fraw_blackopium_display_aw' from dual)
  3  select val
  4  from (select regexp_substr(col, '[[:alnum:]_]+', 1, level) val
  5        from test
  6        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '[[:alnum:]_]+')
  7       )
  8  where regexp_like(val, '^\d+$');

VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
759678

SQL>
```

- subquery returns all *alphanumeric* substrings (that's `regexp_substr`)
- the main query returns values that consist of numbers only (that's `regexp_like`)

Comment: Hi,Littlefoot. thanks for the answer. 
Recursion is superfluous here, only 1 value is needed, the first.Problem,
the desired value is not limited by the sign '_'. 
I think the condition can be dictated like this: Show a sequence of characters of 5 or 6 characters, where 1 character on the left, and 1 character on the right is not a letter